# sql - BETWEEN timeframes with a weird timestamp

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have a column that is populated with a date format that is useful for another application but not the mysql format for timestamps. Here is what it looks like:

`2010.01.28 12:00` ("time" column) instead of the mysql timestamp: `2010-01-28 12:00:00` ("updatetime" column).

I need to do a date specific search between two time periods and for a normal mysql timestamp I would run this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE updatetime BETWEEN '$dateStart' and '$dateEnd'
```

but this doesn't work with the "time" column formatted as it is. I would prefer to keep that column formatted as such as a different application requires that date format, so does anyone know a MYSQL way to search BETWEEN two timeperiods with the `2010.01.28 12:00` format? Running from a PHP script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either format the times in the same format in PHP, or in MySQL

```
WHERE updatetime BETWEEN
        date_format('$datestart','%Y.%m.%d %H:%s')
    AND date_format('$dateend','%Y.%m.%d %H:%s')
```

Comment: +1 from me for thinking about the input-format of the php-vars, forgot about that completly

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(updatetime, "%d.%m.%Y %h:%i") 
BETWEEN '$dateStart' and '$dateEnd'
```

to convert the string into a date - that is if the values of $dateStart and $dateEnd are already in the correct format for comparison with a sql date

Comment: Not usually a good idea to put a function around the field column, which prevents INDEX usage

Comment: @cyberwiki: true and if there is a lot of data in the table i would advice against it as well. but then again i would save the date either as timestamp or in the native date-format and reformat it only where needed otherwise